# Send() / Transfer() Intrinsic gas limits

Tags: solidity, evm

There have been changes to Ethereum that limit send() and transfer() to only have 2300 gas primarily to prevent reentrancy attacks. What I am struggling to understand is if this change was compiler or EVM related. More specifically, if a contract was compiled / deployed with version 0.1.1 and used send() does the fallback function only receive 2300 gas? My intuition tells me yes, but I have been unable to find good information on this.